# SQL query does not work on server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

[this is on server query image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42is1.png) ,    [This is on local DB query image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfucK.png)    I'm trying to execute an SQL query. For birthday it works fine on a local DB, but on the server it does not give any output:

```
SELECT studentname
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR ,birthday ,101)
FROM   birthday
WHERE  DATEADD(
           YEAR
          ,DATEPART(YEAR ,GETDATE())- DATEPART(YEAR ,birthday)
          ,birthday
       ) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE ,GETDATE()) AND CONVERT(DATE ,GETDATE()+7);
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: which error you are getting on live server? there should be some error or there may not be data in birthday table... please check

Comment: You need to share the data of birthday table. `select * from birthday` and show us the data. as I need to check that, is there any data based on your condition or not.

Comment: its not working i don't know why its not working..i have uploaded the data ..

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause filters all data out OR there is not data in the table. Try `SELECT studentname,CONVERT(VARCHAR ,birthday ,101), DATEADD(
           YEAR
          ,DATEPART(YEAR ,GETDATE())- DATEPART(YEAR ,birthday)) as testcolumn
          ,birthday
FROM   birthday` Do you see any data? Check carefully the records you expect to see. What does the last column show

Comment: Just see two images that i have uploaded  ..i have inserted same values on birthday table of Both(on server and LocalDB) and then i am executing date query, on LocalDB works Fine but Not on server ...plz tell me why on server it not giving me data..

Answer (score 0):

I think you made one small mistake,

```
SELECT studentname
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR ,birthday ,101)
FROM   TableName --here it should be table name not the field name
WHERE  DATEADD( 
           YEAR
          ,DATEPART(YEAR ,GETDATE())- DATEPART(YEAR ,birthday)
          ,birthday
       ) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE ,GETDATE()) AND CONVERT(DATE ,GETDATE()+7)
```

So I have checked your images and it clearly shows that you have put wrong condition over there.

See below image and replace 7 with 15 to show data.

[image]

**Updated**

Show me what below query returns,

```
Select DATEADD( YEAR ,DATEPART(YEAR ,GETDATE())- DATEPART(YEAR ,birthday),birthday)
```

It will show you,

```
2016-01-29
2016-01-30
2016-01-31
2016-02-01
```

And execute below query,

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE ,GETDATE())
2016-01-21

SELECT CONVERT(DATE ,GETDATE() + 7)
2016-01-28
```

And you match your condition, how can be satisfied your condition?

If you can understand see below query,

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (StudentName VARCHAR(100),StudentId int,birthday date);
INSERT INTO #Temp (StudentName,StudentId,birthday)
VALUES('tapan',5,'1997-01-29'),
('karan',6,'1997-01-30'),
('ravi',7,'1997-01-31'),
('anand',8,'1997-02-01')
SELECT studentname
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR ,birthday ,101)
FROM   #Temp --here it should be table name not the field name
WHERE  DATEADD( 
           YEAR
          ,DATEPART(YEAR ,GETDATE())- DATEPART(YEAR ,birthday)
          ,birthday
       ) BETWEEN '2016-01-21' AND '2016-01-28'

SELECT studentname,CONVERT(VARCHAR ,birthday ,101), DATEADD( YEAR ,DATEPART(YEAR ,GETDATE())- DATEPART(YEAR ,birthday),birthday) as WhereConditionField FROM #Temp
SELECT DATEADD( YEAR ,DATEPART(YEAR ,GETDATE())- DATEPART(YEAR ,birthday),birthday) as testcolumn FROM #Temp
SELECT CONVERT(DATE ,GETDATE())
SELECT CONVERT(DATE ,GETDATE() + 7)
DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: okay then there must be same error. provide the error message or check the data as per your condition

Comment: i don't  get any error ...but also no data in output only columnname i can see ..

Comment: Rajesh Plz see New Uploaded Image you can clearly Understand my Problem ...plz help me to This...